# ': not a valid identifier for read

Tags: bash, unix, notepad++, cygwin

I use Notepad++ and type:

```
    read s
    echo "$s"
```

The Output is:

[image: <code>': not a valid identifier</code>]

And then I try to put semicolon:

```
read s;
echo "$s"
```

and the Output is:

[image]

I save the file as `q.sh` and run with cygwin but still I cannot use `read` operator so I'm getting confused. I have tried other editors like `vi` also but the output is the same.

What is wrong? How to make it work?

Comment: Your file has windows-style line-endings.  You need to remove them.  See instructions [here](https://www.larshaendler.com/2013/06/10/notepad-unix-to-dos-line-endings/).

Comment: You are also missing `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of the shell script.

Comment: Oh Ok I got it thank you John1024 and DavidPastill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text file that constitutes the shell script was written in Notepad++. This editor saves files as DOS text files by default which, from the Unix point of view, has a superfluous carriage return (`\r`) at the end of each line. This confuses `sh`.

To remove it:

```
$ tr -d '\r' <q.sh >q-new.sh
$ mv q-new.sh q.sh
```

The script *does* lack a `#!`-line (as pointed out in comments), but as long as you run it with an explicit interpreter (`sh q.sh`), this is not needed.

Adding the line

```
#!/bin/sh
```

would (after `chmod +x q.sh`) make running it as `./q.sh` behave exactly the same as running it with `sh q.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to convert the carriage return for Unix, if you have access to Notepad++. 
In Notepad, go on :
Edit -> EOL conversion -> Unix (LF)

In French, it's :
Edition -> Convertir les sauts de ligne -> Converti au format Unix (LF)

It can be faster.